# Can ping but not connect to Samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, samba, network-share

I have installed Samba on my machine (192.168.178.50) and altered /etc/samba/smb.conf to add a share:

```
[vs]
comment = Visual Studio
path = /home/mrt/Dokumente/vs/
browseable = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
```

testparm was ok, I restarted samba.

Then I tried to connect to it from the same computer. smb://localhost works fine. But using smb://192.168.178.50 I do not get a connection. I verified then my IP to be sure:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:26:18:fd:14:e0  
          inet Adresse:192.168.178.50  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
```

ping on .50 works fine. But I still won't get a samba-connection using my LAN IP Address. On the localhost this is of course no problem, but I have a second machine in LAN that should connect to it. It is a Win7 computer (in a VM) that encounters the same issue. ping on 192.168.178.50 works, but a connection to the shares (\192.168.178.50) does not work.

What I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't my computer be able to connect to itself with the LAN IP-Address?

FYI: I am running Kubuntu (utopic), the VM is handled by QEMU in default networking settings, I have 2 physical LAN adapters where I'm using only one

```
$ netstat --inet -nlp
(Es konnten nicht alle Prozesse identifiziert werden; Informationen über
nicht-eigene Processe werden nicht angezeigt; Root kann sie anzeigen.)
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:445           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:139           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55392           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6687            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp   213504      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp   159104      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Comment: Plz, check your open ports:
`$ netstat --inet -nlp`
Can you see the TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP ports 137 and 138 open?

Comment: you are only listening on 127.0.0.1 . change this in your smb.conf `interfaces = 192.168.178.0/24 eth0`