# Can ssh and ping but cannot map to SAMBA drive

Tags: windows, ssh, samba, mappeddrive

I am trying to connect to a linux server which is set up as shares in samba. I am able to ssh and ping to the samba server, but when I attempt to map the drive through windows it says "Windows cannot access \ip\example.

Given that I could ssh to it tells me that the problem comes from the nmb side of things... I have restarted smb, nmb and also iptables, but still unable to connect.

```
*$iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited*
```

testparm smb.conf results below:

```
*$testparm -s /etc/samba/smb.conf 

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[data]"
Processing section "[Xerox]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
[global]
                server string = Samba Server Version %v
                log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
                max log size = 50
                idmap config * : backend = tdb
                cups options = raw

[printers]
                comment = All Printers
                path = /var/spool/samba
                printable = Yes
                print ok = Yes
                browseable = No

[data]
                comment = Data
                path = /data
                admin users = root
                read only = No
                create mask = 0770
                force create mode = 060
                security mask = 0770
                force directory mode = 0770

[Xerox]
                comment = Colour
                path = 142.20.216.47
                printable = Yes
                print ok = Yes*
```

I have read the post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/679298/can-ping-but-not-connect-to-samba) but it seems to be a different scenario. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the firewall rules included in the question, you're allowing ICMP (which includes but is not limited to "ping") and SSH but reject everything else.
Ie, you're rejecting the SMB/CIFS related traffic.

Allowing `137/udp`, `138/udp`, `139/tcp`, `445/tcp` should help.

Comment: uh! Thanks for the input @Håkan Lindqvist ! In my iptables I've added `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT` right before the rules with -j REJECT, but I get the error _iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 11 failed                                                        [FAILED]_. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Turns out `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` is syntax from centos5. Starting from centos6 simply using `-A INPUT` would do the job. Many thanks again.[discussion link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8979)